# inverse Laplace transform of exponential function and gamma function

Tags: exponential-function, gamma-function, inverse-laplace

**I came to this final problem to be solved. I would like to understand a way to tackle this problem:**
Inverse Laplace transform of

$$\frac{e^{-as}}{Γ(bs+c)}$$
I cannot find an easy way of finding an analytical solution, if it exists.